# List WordPress Terms Not Linked

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

In a WordPress theme, how do you list all terms associated with a post, and of a certain taxonomy, and only show terms that are children of set term. And set a custom separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your functions.php:

```
/*
 * Get Terms as a list
 */     
    function get_term_list_not_linked($postID, $tax, $parentTermID, $sep) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $postID, $taxonomy);

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { 

            $termList = array();

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if($term->parent == $parentTermID) {
                    $term_list[] = $term->name;                
                }
            }

            $termList = join( $separator, $termList);

            return $termList;

        } else {
            return null;
        }   

    }
```

And then in the theme file, you call it like this:

```
<?php echo get_term_list_not_linked($postID, $taxonomy, $parentTermID, $separator); ?>
```

Here is an example that gets all terms in the 'video-type' taxonomy, that are direct-children of the term with ID 5, and separate the terms with a comma and space:

```
<?php echo get_term_list_not_linked($post->ID, 'video-type', 5, ', '); ?>
```

Comment: No, I was using the new Stackoverflow question & answer feature.